# Fastboot command not working as expected

Tags: adb, fastboot

When I connect my android phone in fastboot mode and enter fastboot devices ,I get no output at terminal ,but when I enter fastboot -i 0x1ebf devices I get an output.I need -i option with every other fastboot commands too. Why ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fastboot` utility had an internal whitelist for USB vendor IDs, which included only some major Android device vendors:

```
0x0451    Texas Instruments
0x0502    Acer
0x05c6    Qualcomm
0x0955    Nvidia
0x0b05    Asus
0x0bb4    HTC
0x0fce    Sony Ericsson
0x18d1    Google
0x22b8    Motorola
0x2314    INQ Mobile
0x413c    DELL
0x8087    Intel
```

In the [AOSP commit from 2015-08-10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/e1746fda6a30ebaea22e492bc7821a9dee5face8%5E!/) this USB vendor ID whitelist was removed, therefore new `fastboot` versions should work with all Android devices without needing the `-i 0xXXXX` option (now the option just limits the selection in case multiple Android devices from different vendors are connected). However, the most current platform-tools release (23) at the time of writing this answer does not yet have this commit included, therefore you will need to keep using the `-i 0xXXXX` option for some time.